# Is all communication from frontend to backend done via routes?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm working on a vuejs/express fullstack web app, and I know you can specify endpoints on the server like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})
```

Which you can then hit from the client to display the home page.

But I'm wondering what about when you don't need to go to a 'route'? For example, you just want to send some data from client to server to do some calculations and then send data back to the client - do you still specify an endpoint e.g /FunctionName and access it from the frontend in the same way or is there some other way to call a function in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the 'express' way to define endpoints (or routes), regardless if it will return an html page like the example you've specified, or do some computation by calling other functions with user-specified parameters.

As a basic example:

```
app.post('/myendpoint', function (req, res) {
  returnValues = callMyFunction(req)
  res.send(returnValues)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! So what would happen if someone then actually tried to go onto url.com/FunctionName in the browser?

Comment: That's a good question and I think the best way to illustrate would be for you to mock out an express instance with a route that does just that and see what the browser responds with. In general, though, it will likely present you with a JSON structure that the express route gives back when the request is finished. You can also go to your 'network' tab in your browser's development tools and watch the request from that perspective.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much! I didn't know if I was doing things wrong by specifying an endpoint for every function i had on the server